# Get sublime text 2 (sublimecodeintel) to parse mason

Tags: perl

So Sublime Text 2 seems to getting a lot of love lately. I am using the Sublime Code intel plugin, https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel for auto completion. The problem is, it does not recognize .mi files as MASON files. I looked into the lexer and it does have the keywords in place. How do I force it to be parsed as MASON?

Running "Set Syntax: " on ctrl+shift+p, does not show a MASON option.

Comment: Thanks dgw, I will put it there. I just cant seem to get which question to ask on which stackexchange forum :/